# How to load GeoTIFF info by gdal library like Matlab geotiffinfo function

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, c++

**geotiffinfo** function in Matlab show different geotiff info from GeoTIFF images.

I use gdal library for read images info.

How to load GeoTIFF info by gdal2 like Matlab **geotiffinfo** function?

Comment: Do you mean that it should be done with c++? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve information about a GeoTiff, GDAL provides three basic tools.

The first is using the 'gdalinfo' utility, called from the commandline ([doc here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html)).

If you don't want to use the commandline, but need that same information, as of GDAL 2.1 the C interface has the function `GDALInfo` ([doc here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__utils_8h.html#a39aaaa537474fead1ef4575e61e9b96d)).

The third option, which is probably least-desirable, is to individually query each property through the `Get*` functions of `GDALDataset`.